# See all the errors related to a build at the same time in Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

I recently submitted an update to my Android app, and I got an error regarding a storage permission that I was using.

I fixed the error that was mentioned, and uploaded a new AAB. While uploading the AAB I got an error about a defective version for a library that is included in my AAB.

Is there any way I can check all the errors from the console at the same time? I would like to avoid fixing the current error, and finding out that another one will be reported on the Google Play console, it would be helpful to receive all errors at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this, because this is done on Google Play's servers and keep changing because of changes on policies and supported versions.

BUT, it is fairly easy to drag & drop aab file to an internal testing track to find if there is a problem or not, and sometimes it will show you more than one error.